# Why was this answer suggested as a "low quality post" by the system?

Tags: discussion

Of all posts this one? Seriously?

Was it because it had no Latin characters and even the numerals were fullwidth?

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/30361

If that was indeed the case is there anything we can do to improve the low quality detection system?

Or was it a ["gotcha"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)?

Comment: The low quality low quality detection system.

Comment: More often than not I find it's an issue of how long the post is (in characters) that trips the system.  It's easier to say more with fewer characters in Japanese.

Comment: @ajsmart Also I noticed comments in Japanese on this site appear longer and bulkier than what I was used to but only because of Japanese characters being fullwidth. Doing a  rough character count, I still think that answer is longer than what the system usually feeds to the low quality review queue on an English language site. I could be wrong.

Comment: @EddieKal Have the Stack Exchange developers made the criteria for the 'low quality post' flagging algorithm public?  I was unaware of any capabilities by the moderators/high rep users to adjust the algorithm.

Comment: @ajsmart I did a bit of research today and found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality), well, dunno what to say.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I have been told this is not a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work/157172#157172)

> audits (the thing you mentioned here) are probably not applicable in this situation. First off, looking at the linked review it doesn't say it is a "Review Audit" (see here). Secondly, Japanese doesn't have review audits enabled, since it's not big enough to warrant them. (@bobble)

Therefore, please disregard this information below.

---

[There is another possibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143380/451368)

> We throw a few known cases into the queue* as "gotchas" to keep people from just nailing "Looks Good" or "Close" or whatever without reading the questions.
>
> If you see one of these just handle it normally, we're probably going to make them a little more... subtle over time. For now we're pulling from really obvious sources: spam, and uncontested high quality posts.

Hmm... back then that trick wasn't in place on sites outside of SO, not sure about now.

> @Martin This is currently only enabled on SO, it will eventually be on everywhere. – Kevin Montrose♦ Aug 18 '12 at 17:53